How can I validate if a field value is bigger than another using Ajv JSON schema validator?
Using ajv is it possible to get a validation error if minPrice is bigger than maxPrice?
How can I do it, preferably following the JSON schema standard.

Yes, ajv supports defining custom validation rules and conditions through JSON Schema.


{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "minPrice": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "maxPrice": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": ["minPrice", "maxPrice"],
  "dependencies": {
    "minPrice": ["maxPrice"],
    "maxPrice": ["minPrice"]
  },
  "validate": function(response, errors) {
    if (response.minPrice > response.maxPrice) {
      errors.push({ keyword: "maxPrice", message: "min Price cannot be greater than max Price" });
    }
    return false;
  }
}




Does not work.
strict mode: unknown keyword: "validate"
